# Firefox, Safari, Edge not loading JS file using require()

Tags: javascript, require

I have a React app and have installed `annyang`.

I am calling this at the top of my file using 
`const annyang = require('annyang');`

In Chrome if I `console.log(annyang)` it returns an object but in all other browsers it returns null.

Why is this happening in all browsers except Chrome and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using any module loader? Because `require()` should not be used directly in your browser.

Comment: Have you checked whether it is supported by the browsers. As far as I know it is only supported by chrome so far (see https://caniuse.com/imports if I'm not mistaking)

Comment: Interestingly this is under development: https://github.com/TalAter/annyang/issues/290 but I don't know the status.

Answer (score 0):

DOH! Those browsers don't support speech recognition!

Answer (score 0):

That's what happens in browsers that do not support the Speech Recognition API.

[annyang](https://www.talater.com/annyang/) uses the browser's own speech recognition engine, according to the Speech Recognition API. If the browser you use does not support it, then the annyang object will equal to null.

You can see this in the [code itself](https://github.com/TalAter/annyang/blob/8e28f13f80804e6a93d3e1b8f8ecb9d8844e0b3e/src/annyang.js#L41).